# Filtering a GridView programatically with Checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, filter

I'm creating a project tracker ASP.net wbsite with C# for my codebehind. My default view has a GridView that queries a SQL Server DB, and one of the columns is Project Status (ProjStatus), which can have 5 different options (In Progress, Pending, Complete, Postponed, Cancelled).

Now, I need to create an incremental filter using a checkbox list. For example, if I select the checkbox for "In Progress" I would only want to see "In Progress" projects, but if I also check the "Pending" checkbox then I would want to see both and so forth.

I previously only had 3 status (In Progress, Pending and Complete) and I had solved this problem by hard coding each checkbox combination using if statements, but since there's 5 now there's too many possible combinations and it would take me too long to do that. Any suggestions to do this programatically in my codebehind?

Thank you!

Edit:

I was previously using RadioButtons but I had to change that earlier today at my manager's request. This was the code I was previously using, combined with a FilterExpression on the SQLDataSource

```
        if (radioStatus.SelectedItem.Value == "Active")
        {
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "[PROJ_STATUS] = 'Active'";
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else if (radioStatus.SelectedItem.Value == "Pending")
        {
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "[PROJ_STATUS] = 'Pending'";
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else if (radioStatus.SelectedItem.Value == "Postponed")
        {
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "[PROJ_STATUS] = 'Postponed'";
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else if (radioStatus.SelectedItem.Value == "Cancelled")
        {
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "[PROJ_STATUS] = 'Cancelled'";
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "[PROJ_STATUS] = 'Complete'";
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: can I see what you have tried?

Comment: I added an edit with my code, however, that was a solution that I had previously implemented with radiobuttons so there was no incremental filtering since you could only select one option (on purpose)

Comment: Here is a case with multiple filter values that are checked from checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation lacks some implementation details but the logic should be relatively similar anyway. For a low number of checkboxes, I believe you could use Linq this way without mapping the checkboxes to the appropriate properties (in a scenario with many properties you'd do that to keep the code DRY).

```
List<Project> allProjects = yourQuery.ToList(); // Assuming "Project" is your type
List<Project> filteredProjects = new List<Project>(); 

if (inProgressCheckBox.IsChecked)
    filteredProjects.AddRange(allProjects.Where(p => p.InProgress));
if (pendingCheckBox.IsChecked)
    filteredProjects.AddRange(allProjects.Where(p => p.Pending));
if (completeCheckBox.IsChecked)
    filteredProjects.AddRange(allProjects.Where(p => p.Complete));
if (postponedCheckBox.IsChecked)
    filteredProjects.AddRange(allProjects.Where(p => p.Postponed));
if (cancelledCheckBox.IsChecked)
    filteredProjects.AddRange(allProjects.Where(p => p.Cancelled));

filteredProjects = filteredProjects.Distinct();
```

This is not optimized, but it should do the job well enough. You'd simply have to bind `filteredProjects` to your grid's datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have checked `project_status` check boxes as InProgrss, Pending and Complete then making a `string` expression separated by `,` like `InProgress,Pending,Complete`.

```
CheckBoxList projects = (CheckBoxList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CheckBoxList1");

List<string> projectsList = new List<string>();

string expression = "";

foreach (ListItem item in projects.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
        projectsList.Add(item.Text);
}

expression = string.Join(",", projectsList); // add , inside projects (InProgress,Pending,Complete)
```